# Simple jQuery question

Tags: jquery

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#red').click(function(){
    $('#write').text('red');
});

</script>
<form id="formId" name="formName" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="clickDiv red" id="red">mmmmmmm</div></td>
      <td><div class="clickDiv green"></div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="write"></div>
  <input type="radio" name="satir1" value="red" />
  <input type="radio" name="satir1" value="green" />
</form>
</body>
```

This doesn't work.

```
<body>
<form id="formId" name="formName" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="clickDiv red" id="red">mmmmmmm</div></td>
      <td><div class="clickDiv green"></div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="write"></div>
  <input type="radio" name="satir1" value="red" />
  <input type="radio" name="satir1" value="green" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#red').click(function(){
    $('#write').text('red');
});
</script>
</body>
```

This works. Why? How can I use script part in the header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the first example's javascript in the [jQuery document ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). This will cause the code to wait until the page elements are rendered into the javascript DOM before it executes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#red').click(function(){
        $('#write').text('red');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the first version of the code(which doesn't work), the element with id# red is still not available in DOM hence the jquery selector doesn't find any matching element.
In the second verison the element is available.

However as a good practice it is always advisable to use the jquery ready function to execute any script that needs to be run as soon as DOM is ready. It goes in the following formats:

```
$(<YOUR FUNCTION>);
OR
$(document).ready(<YOUR FUNCTION>));
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no difference, just one is a short form of another.

Answer (score 1):

Use .ready with your first code snippet: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#red').click(function(){
        $('#write').text('red');
    });
});
```

In your first example #white doesn't exist yet when the script is executed, so you need to wait until the document is ready.

Comment: Note that `$(someFunction)` is prefered over `$(document).ready(someFunction)`

Comment: Where does it say that $(someFunction) is preferred? I see that $().ready(handler) is not recommended but I don't see anything about $(someFunction) being preferred.

Comment: based jointly on the principles that (1) boilerplate should be as unobtrusive as possible and (2) JS is transferred over the wire so it should be as compact as is readably possible.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery initiating before the dom is ready.  You should always wrap jquery in your header in this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Insert jQuery here
});
```

For more info on the `.ready()` function: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()

Answer (score 1):

Both are bad options.  The first does not work because the document is not fully constructed in the browser.
Try this:

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
    $('#red').click(function()
    {
        $('#write').text('red');
    });
});
```

Comment: *"Both are bad options."* Why is the second code example bad?

Comment: Use of the .ready() function is run after the DOM is loaded and before the page contents are loaded.  Not using the .ready() function has no such guarantee.

Comment: *"...after the DOM is loaded and before the page contents are loaded."* How can it be after the DOM is loaded, but before the page contents? The DOM is created *from* the page content. By placing your script inside the closing `<body>` tag, it ensures that the rest of the content is available.

Comment: This is possible through the magic of RTFM.  http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29

Comment: @dwb You're missing patrick dw's point - The way browsers render pages and execute JS ensures that JS placed after an element **will** have access to the element, rendering doc ready irrelevant.

Comment: @jball I believe you miss my point.  Using $(document).ready() allows you to place the JS code anywhere on the page without depending on a side effect.

Comment: @dwb The original question is specifically about where the JS code is placed in relation to the markup. Also, rendering order is not a side effect. It is standardized behavior.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the html() option and not the text option

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(function() {
$('#red').click(function(){
    $('#write').html('red');
});});</script>
```

Comment: This won't affect the ineffectiveness of the code that the OP is seeing in the first case.

Comment: jball is right. that's not the case. but thanks. Why do I have to prefer .html() to .text()?

Comment: @borayeris: You don't. When setting only text content, use `.text()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the new `live` jquery function instead and use `html` to put the content ;)

```
$('#red').live('click', function(){
  $('#write').html('red');
});
```

More infos : http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Bad mojo - using doc ready is highly preferable performance-wise, unless the OP is going to be dynamically adding other divs with `id="red"` after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: @jball: +1 This is an example of the way `.live()` is painfully abused.